# Does Hagrid ever deduct house points?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

In the later books, Hagrid is a teacher, but I don't recall him ever deducting house points.

Does he ever deduct house points?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### In the books as published, he only ever adds points, and only does this once

The only time in the books as published that Hagrid changes house points is in the fifth book, when he awards 10 points for Hermione answering a question correctly about Thestrals.

> ‘Righ’, now, who can tell me why some o’ yeh can see ’em an’ some can’t?’
> Hermione raised her hand.
> ‘Go on then,’ said Hagrid, beaming at her.
> ‘The only people who can see Thestrals,’ she said, ‘are people who have seen death.’
> **‘Tha’s exactly right,’ said Hagrid solemnly, ‘ten points ter Gryffindor.** Now, Thestrals –’
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 21 "The Eye of the Snake"</sub>

### In some of the earlier drafts though, Hagrid can be seen deducting points as well.

On [July 9th 1998](https://i.imgur.com/zbINiaj.jpg) (a week after the second book released), J.K. Rowling did a photoshoot for the Guardian at Waterstones cafe in Edinburgh with  photographer Murdo MacLeod.

In one of the photographs a draft of the Salamander lesson in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* can be seen.

> [image]
>
> (Salamanders)
> The warmth was
> 'Fork a coal - use the tongs. Seamus - excellent, show
> (Hugh bonfire)
> 'Do you mean you've dragged us down here to help you <strike>with</strike> burn your stinking rubbish?' said Malfoy
> **'Righ'!' thundered Hagrid. 'Ten points from Slytherin for cheek!'**
> Harry and Ron [added: grinning broadly,] made thumbs up signs at Hagrid from behind Malfoy's back.
> 'This is supposed to be a Care of Magical Creatures class' said Malfoy, two pink patches burning on his white face, 'We're not supposed to be helping you with your gamekeeping duties! My parents don't send me here to learn how to do -
> **'Righ' - ten more points from Slytherin - an' five each from you two an' all!' Hagrid bellowed, pointing at Crabbe and Goyle, whose faces froze 'I'm - I'm a teacher, me! An' don' you forget it Malfoy!'**
> 'Salamanders!'
> 'Blimey,' said Dean Thomas, quitely from behind Harry

This lesson still happens in the published book, just off-screen, and thus we don't see any points deducted.

> Lessons started again next day. **The last thing anyone felt like doing was spending two hours in the grounds on a raw January morning, but Hagrid had provided a bonfire full of salamanders for their enjoyment, and they spent an unusually good lesson collecting dry wood and leaves to keep the fire blazing, while the flame-loving lizards scampered up and down the crumbling, white-hot logs.** The first Divination lesson of the new term was much less fun; Professor Trelawney was now teaching them palmistry, and she lost no time in informing Harry that he had the shortest life-lines she had ever seen.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - Chapter 12 - "The Patronus"</sub>

I don't believe anything is ever said to imply that the lesson did *not* go according to the discarded draft version, so perhaps it can still be counted.

Comment: The source for the date and location of the photo is personal communication with the photographer.

Comment: For those keeping count, the final tally is +10 Gryffindor, -30 Slytherin.

Comment: You have good eyes. Even if I squint very hard at that picture I can barely make out the number of points that Hagrid is deducting from Malfoy.

Comment: @Stef - "[Ten points from Slytherin](https://i.imgur.com/bbOhg5v.png)" and "[ten more points from Slytherin](https://i.imgur.com/YFNSlob.png)". I'm pretty confident about both of those readings.

Comment: @ibid Are those two screenshots from the same image in your answer? I tried zooming in but it's unreadable; most likely because of compression

Comment: @Clockwork - The image in the answer is shrunk using SE's size modifiers. Remove the last letter from the url. After that a bit of photoshop will yield those slightly more readable images.

Comment: If you can identify the exact date of the photo based on the newspaper that the guy in the background is reading, I'll give you a bounty.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "Enhance."

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [I'm expecting a large bounty.](https://i.imgur.com/gAHYUW7.jpg)

Comment: Cool how far ahead she worked the books

Comment: Curious what other unpublished draft material we know of.

Comment: @TheAsh - While it's right after the CoS release, it's only one year before the PoA release. And we also know that the first draft was already submitted to the editor sometime prior to August 18th 1998 (the earliest dated editorial correspondence for the book). It could very well be that she was actually a lot further along at the time of this picture, and just dug out an old page for the photoshoot.

Comment: @ibid I think she deliberately chose this page because it was already edited out of any drafts she had already submitted. It means that she does not provide any accidental spoilers (imagine if she used one of the pages from the Shrieking Shack exposition dumps and everyone already knew that Ron's pet rat REDACTED), but it also means that anyone who does end up reading the page gets a nice little easter egg.

Comment: How can you prove that the guy with the journal ain't trying to mislead us by reading an older newspaper? /s